# Can Customer portal user create records in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I want to create record for one sobject which is child object of standard sobject account through customer portal. But when I click on "create new" the standard edit page is shown on customer portal, but after entering different field values when I click to save it just give me one message below:

**Insufficient Privileges 
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.**

What should I do to create record from customer portal?

Answer (score 0):

You must to adjust Custom Object Permissions. If you have an administrator profile do this:

- Go to "Setup" -> "Manage Users" -> "Profiles"
- Select profile you want to edit
- At the next page click "Edit" button and scroll down to "Custom Object Permissions"
- In order to create a new object record you must have "Read" and "Create" access
- If that is not the case - select that checkboxes and click on the "Save" button

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is not solving my purpose.
After doing above task also, it is showing same error. Do you have any other idea?